# How to properly release Python C API GIL from main thread

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

I'm trying to embed Python in a C++ multithreaded program.
What I do is calling two statistical functions from the Python C API to perform the `Two Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test` and the `Two Sample Anderson-Darling Test` on some data that I collect. So I'm just embedding Python in my code, I'm not extending it or using my own Python functions.

I recently found out that in order to run a multithreaded program that uses the Python C API you need to handle properly the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and when ever you use a Python C API function you need to acquire the GIL and then release it when you're done using the API functions.

The thing that I still don't understand is how to properly release the GIL from the main thread in order to let the others execute the Python code.

I tried this (**option 1**):

```
 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int n = 4;
    std::thread threads[n];

    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    PyEval_SaveThread();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(exec, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me a `segmentation fault` when calling `Py_Finalize()`.

So I tried this (**option 2**):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int n = 4;
    std::thread threads[n];

    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    PyThreadState * Py_UNBLOCK_THREADS
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(exec, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    Py_BLOCK_THREADS    
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and this (**option 3**):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int n = 4;
    std::thread threads[n];

    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(exec, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

With both these last two options the code runs but ends with this error:

`Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1289, in _shutdown
    assert tlock.locked()
AssertionError:`

**EDIT:**
The code that is executed by the spawned threads is this:

```
double limited_rand(double lower_bound, double upper_bound) {
    return lower_bound + (rand() / (RAND_MAX / (upper_bound-lower_bound) ) );
}


double exec_1(std::vector<int> &left_sample, std::vector<int> &right_sample) {
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); // Acquiring GIL for thread-safe usage Python C API

    PyObject* scipy_stats_module = PyImport_ImportModule("scipy.stats"); // importing "scipy.stats" module

    import_array();
    npy_intp left_nparray_shape[] = {(npy_intp)left_sample.size()}; // Size of left nparray's first dimension
    PyObject* left_sample_nparray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, left_nparray_shape, NPY_INT, &left_sample[0]); // Creating numpy array with 1 dimension, taking "dim" as a dummy, elements are integers, and the data is taken from "sample1" as a int* pointer
    npy_intp right_nparray_shape[] = {(npy_intp)right_sample.size()}; // Size of right nparray's first dimension
    PyObject* right_sample_nparray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, right_nparray_shape, NPY_INT, &right_sample[0]);

    PyObject* ks_2samp = PyObject_GetAttrString(scipy_stats_module, "ks_2samp");
    Py_DecRef(scipy_stats_module);

    PyObject* ks_2samp_return_val = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(ks_2samp, left_sample_nparray, right_sample_nparray, NULL);
    Py_DecRef(ks_2samp);
    Py_DecRef(right_sample_nparray);
    Py_DecRef(left_sample_nparray);

    double p_value = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(ks_2samp_return_val, 1));
    Py_DecRef(ks_2samp_return_val);

    PyGILState_Release(gstate); // Releasing GIL
    return p_value;
}


void initialize_c_2d_int_array(int*& c_array, unsigned long row_length_c_array, std::vector<int> &row1, std::vector<int> &row2) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row_length_c_array; i++) {
        c_array[i] = row1[i];
        c_array[row_length_c_array + i] = row2[i];
    }
}
double exec_2(std::vector<int> &left_sample, std::vector<int> &right_sample){
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); // Acquiring GIL for thread-safe usage Python C API

    PyObject* scipy_stats_module = PyImport_ImportModule("scipy.stats"); // importing "scipy.stats" module
                                                                         //            import_array();
    unsigned long n_cols = std::min(left_sample.size(), right_sample.size());
    int* both_samples = (int*) (malloc(2 * n_cols * sizeof(int)));
    initialize_c_2d_int_array(both_samples, n_cols, left_sample, right_sample);
    npy_intp dim3[] = {2, (npy_intp) n_cols};
    PyObject* both_samples_nparray = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dim3, NPY_INT, both_samples);

    PyObject* anderson_ksamp = PyObject_GetAttrString(scipy_stats_module, "anderson_ksamp");
    Py_DecRef(scipy_stats_module);

    PyObject* anderson_2samp_return_val = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(anderson_ksamp, both_samples_nparray, NULL);
    Py_DecRef(anderson_ksamp);
    Py_DecRef(both_samples_nparray);
    free(both_samples);

    double p_value = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(anderson_2samp_return_val, 2));
    Py_DecRef(anderson_2samp_return_val);

    PyGILState_Release(gstate); // Releasing GIL

    return p_value;
}


void exec(int thread_id) {
    std::vector<int> left_sample;
    std::vector<int> right_sample;

    int n = 50;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

        int size = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            left_sample.push_back(limited_rand(0, 100));
            right_sample.push_back(limited_rand(0, 100));
        }

        exec_1(left_sample, right_sample);
        exec_2(left_sample, right_sample);
    }
}
```

The functions where I use the Python C API are only **exec_1** and **exec_2**, while **exec** has just the job to call the repeatedly on new random data. This is the simplest code I could think of that mimics the behavior of my real code. I've also left out every type of error checking when using the Python APIs for a better readability.

Without any other choice I'll run my code like **option 2** or **option 3** and forget about the error, but I would really like to understand what's going on. Can you help me?

P.S. I'm running Python 3.6.1 under a macOS 10.12.5 system using Xcode 8.3.3. If you need more details let me know.

Comment: Option 3 is correct. What do those threads do? If they call the interpreter to execute python-code or use the C-api, they need to acquire the GIL individually before doing so.

Comment: Every thread calls `PyGILState_Ensure()` before using any API function and then calls `PyGILState_Release` when it doesn't need to call those functions anymore. But what I don't understand is the error I get at the end of the program's execution. If you want to, I can add the code of the function that is executed by every thread

Comment: You should do that

Comment: @user2722968 Added the code

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock

Comment: @user2357112 I know that page. I've already looked at it. It doesn't say anything about why I'm getting that error

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use multi-threading? Multi-threaded python is a bad choice for anything that is CPU intensive, as it is often slower than running the same thing single-threaded.

Comment: @Dunes No particular reason. I just wanted to make use of all the available cores to make my program run faster. But now that you say that I'll do some tests to see if I really need that.

Comment: The problem relates to the GIL. No other (python) thread can run whilst another thread has the GIL. So your program is still single threaded, just with a load of extra context switches thrown in. For this low level of parallelisation you wish to use the unix utility [`parallel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel) instead.

Comment: @Dunes I've run a couple of tests and in my case this parallelization is actually speeding up the execution. It probably won't be the best, but it's still better than single thread

Answer (score 0):

***option1***:

I think is giving you a segmentation fault because you called PyEval_SaveThread() (which releases the gil, returns a saved thread state, and sets the current thread state to NULL).

Py_Finalize will try to free all memory associated with the interpreter, and I guess this included the main thread state. So you can either capture this state with:

```
 PyEval_InitThreads(); //initialize and aquire the GIL
 //release the GIL, store thread state, set the current thread state to NULL
 PyThreadState *mainThreadState = PyEval_SaveThread();

 *main code segment*

 //re-aquire the GIL (re-initialize the current thread state)
 PyEval_RestoreThread(mainThreadState); 

 Py_Finalize();
 return 0;
```

Or you can immediately call *PyEval_ReleaseLock()* after calling *PyEval_InitThreads()* since it looks like the main code segment does not use any embedded python. I had a similar problem and that seemed to fix it.

***NOTE***: Other threads will still need to aquire/release the GIL wherever necessary